# Rails: How to implement single-attribute AJAX updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I want single-attribute AJAX updates e.g. "Click on row label in a table to toggle public/private flag". What's the best strategy for implementing this? Use the `update` method in controller or a custom method?

Comment: Thank you! You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have some compelling reason to use a custom method, just use the normal update, sending your typical `object[attr] = value` payload. It's simple, works out of the box, and adheres to REST.

Comment: The UI feedback would in most cases be quite different to the Edit/Update scenario (e.g. just a flash "Object is now public" instead of "Object was successfully updated"). Wouldn't my `update` method be cluttered with heaps of `if/then` clauses?

Comment: If you depend on flash messages then this might be one of those compelling reasons.  Then again, in an Ajax update, you know on the client side which button was pressed, and what the user intended to do.  What you might do is ignore or skip sending flash messages if the update is Ajax, then on the client side, determine the message based on the user's action and the status of the response.  This way the controller stays thin, and isn't muddied up with what's essentially view logic.